# Making serveral python files to an executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have two Python scripts, one as User Interface and one as background process. I need both of them because there is a sub-process and the UI. However I want it together get a executable.

I tried it with py2exe, which can only compile one of them.
Next I used **pyinstaller** but that has the same problem

`pyinstaller user_interface.py`

# and with **py2exe**

```py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is some kind of packaging. First try to create a package using setup.py which you can use directly through python console by importing that package. and then you can create an executable out of it. Please refer the example in mentioned link.

Please refer this link: [real python tutorial](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small launcher script that spawns both processes, and then package that file.
I never used py2exe or pyinstaller, so I don't know how python dependencies are managed. If having code split in several files is a problem, then you can just concatenate you two existing scripts and the launcher in one single file.